# Explicitly stop p4 submit operation in perforce

Tags: perforce

I want to stop perforce p4 submit operation through the change-submit hook. The submit operation should wait until the hook operation is completed and should fail to submit if the hook operation returns false.

Answer (score 1):

> The submit operation should wait until the hook operation is completed and should fail to submit if the hook operation returns false.

You are describing the behavior of a change-submit trigger.  Note that "false" means a non-zero return code from the executable specified by the trigger.